# Running Nextflow Head Job on the Login Node of an HPC cluster while Launching from Nextflow Tower

Tags: slurm, hpc, nextflow

I'm trying to launch a Nextflow program called "main.nf" and I usually run the nextflow head job from a screen session on the login node of an HPC cluster using the following command:

Head Job:

```bash
nextflow run main.nf -profile test
```

This command uses the configuration defined in test.config to launch a series of **SLURM** jobs. I monitor these using **Nextflow Tower** with the **-with-tower** flag which grants a web link to the workflow progress.

I am now looking to launch pipelines directly from **Nextflow Tower** to readily access logs without manually navigating **work** subdirectories. However, I need the **main Nextflow head job to execute on the login node**, preferably in a screen session, while the workflow tasks/processes are dispatched to SLURM compute nodes as usual. This is due to the lack of internet access in our SLURM compute nodes which means I cannot connect to the tower api, a restriction not present on the login node.

Additionally, any slurm job in our HPC cluster has a max available wall clock time of 7 days, and I'm hoping the nextflow head job runs for a time longer than that, hence the usage of screen.

When I configure a new compute environment in nextflow tower its asking me to specify a **Head queue name**. If I leave it blank, it still launches it on a compute node as a slurm job. I tried specifying **"local"** but then the pipeline looks for a slurm partition called "local" which does not exist.

Is there a way to force the nextflow head job to run on the login node of the cluster? Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Tower Agent for other reasons in my setting, but from the documentation of Tower I'd take that what you want is not configureable currently. However, I think it should be possible to create a hacky workaround like this:

Create a new executable script with the alias `sbatch` which handles the case that you specify --queue=local and run the script using `bash` instead. If other queues are specified, use the original `sbatch` (by specifying the absolute path to this one) and forward all parameters.

Alternatively you can try to play with the environment-variables configureable in Tower and set a different $PATH for your head-job to use your `sbatch`-mocking script instead, then you can omit the `--queue` handling.

You probably also have to submit a slurm placeholder-job from which your `sbatch` returns the job-id to be monitored. That job should run while your local job runs and stop after your command finishes obviously. You could use a script calling an endless `sleep 10` and waiting for a specific flag file to be created (when your workflow finishes) to break this loop. Maybe you will also need some solution to forward the nextflow-output to the slurm-jobs-output. I guess it should suffice to simply overwrite the output-file with your `bash` cmd output.

PS: Probably a better solution would be to ask your HPC-admins if they could create a queue for your head-jobs where the nodes do have internet access AND/OR file a feature request to the Nextflow Tower developers.